# What status code does Apache return when ProxyPass max is exceeded?

Tags: apache-2.2, proxypass

From http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

> max   1...n
>
> Maximum number of connections that will be allowed to the
>   backend server. The default for this limit is the number of threads
>   per process in the active MPM. In the Prefork MPM, this is always 1,
>   while with other MPMs it is controlled by the ThreadsPerChild
>   directive.

What does Apache return when this is exceeded?